# get values from table in column from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I work in a php/wordpress project, and I have table inserted in column in my database like this:

[image: meta_value]

I like to display values of this table on each input text

so for that I tried to do this :

```
 $mats= get_post_meta($product_id, '_mats', true);
<?php 
     if (!empty($mats)){
        foreach ($mats as $key => $value) {
?>
         <div><input type="text" class="regular-text pro_ele simple variable external grouped" name="mats[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" label_class="pro_title"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img style="height: 20px;width: 20px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Ua_3.21_prohibitory-no_entry.svg"/></a></div>
  <?php      
        }

     }
   ?>
```

the result is this : [image]

but this is what I need: [image]

Someone please can help me ? thanks for all.

Comment: can you show the returned array?

Comment: the array is in meta_value in the first picture

Comment: can you post your meta_value array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the $value in below line to $value[0] and it will work.

```
<div><input type="text" class="regular-text pro_ele simple variable external grouped" name="mats[]" value="<?php echo $value[0]; ?>" label_class="pro_title"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img style="height: 20px;width: 20px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Ua_3.21_prohibitory-no_entry.svg"/></a></div>
```

Comment: thank you @Yamu so I need an other loop for each value